# Can you declare a pointer as extern in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, legacy

I have the following bit of legacy C++ code that does not compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

extern ostream *debug;
```

GCC (g++) complains: "expected initializer before ‘*’ token"

Looking around it seems more common to declare these as external references, like this:

```
extern ostream& debug;
```

Why is a pointer not valid, but a reference is in this situation?

SOLUTION:

The real problem, as mentioned below is that the std:: namespace specifier is missing. Apparently, this was common in older C++ code.

Comment: not sure if this would be a proper response, but I think visual studio is fine with that sort of thing.

Comment: You'll probably find that the "older C++ code" expected to be compiled with a compiler that either did not recognize or did not enforce namespaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can declare a pointer using extern. Your error is most likely you forgot to qualify using `std::` :

```
// note the header is cstdio in C++. stdio.h is deprecated
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

extern std::ostream *debug;
```

Comment: Ah yes, namespaces were not always necessary for standard C++ libraries.

Comment: yes. those were the time before C++ became a standard. you used to include iostream.h , and use ostream without qualifying it. but nowadays, c++ is a standard, and it requires you to use std:: :)